# HTML type bullet in java

Tags: java, html, css, swing

I need use ascii character as a bullet point with html content in swing application. I found [this](http://www.artishock.net/coding/css-list-styling-using-ascii-special-characters/) article and it works with browser exactly i want but not with java. I suppose that css tags won't supported in java according to [this.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/CSS.html) May be i'm wrong.

I like to know is there a workaround for this. Another constrain that i have is not to use images as bullet points.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: for full HTML5 support I'd suggest integrating your Swing application with JavaFX `WebView`. see here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13718130/1133011

Answer (score 1):

would HTML entities work?

```
  • &#8226; &bull;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
styleSheet.addRule("ul{list-style-type:circle;margin:0px 20px;}");
```

Comment: That'll add the circle type bullet. But i need more than that like having ascii character as the bullet. Like in the article i said.