# JEditorPane with Javascript and CSS support

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane, jeditorpane

I am working on Swing using `JEditorPane` but it's  not supporting the Javascript or some advanced tag like `<object>` etc. and not supporting the color, font style size etc.

Is there any solution so that editor pane can display the HTML file as it is being displayed in normal HTML browser?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- current `Java6/7` supporting only (upto) `Html 3.2` with reduced support for `css`,
- for `Html5` and quite full `css support` to use `JavaFx Components`,
- there are custom Java libraries with (full???) support of Html4/5, css and js but I'd be suggest to use `JavaFX` instead

Comment: sir i am having to add and remove javafx control on swing window when JFXPanel is removed it cant be again added on the container window

Comment: Hi, can you provide more information about custom libraries that support html5? JavaFx WebView crash when using Chinese Input Method on macOS.

Answer (score 29):

+1 to mKorbel.

Use [JavaFX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/index.html) [`WebView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) which supports HTML5 by integrating it with Swing.

Here is an example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import static javafx.concurrent.Worker.State.FAILED;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEvent;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleSwingBrowser implements Runnable {
    private JFXPanel jfxPanel;
    private WebEngine engine;

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private JLabel lblStatus = new JLabel();

    private JButton btnGo = new JButton("Go");
    private JTextField txtURL = new JTextField();
    private JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();

    private void initComponents() {
        jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();

        createScene();

        ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
            @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                loadURL(txtURL.getText());
            }
        };

        btnGo.addActionListener(al);
        txtURL.addActionListener(al);

        progressBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 18));
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);

        JPanel topBar = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 0));
        topBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 5, 3, 5));
        topBar.add(txtURL, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        topBar.add(btnGo, BorderLayout.EAST);


        JPanel statusBar = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 0));
        statusBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 5, 3, 5));
        statusBar.add(lblStatus, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        statusBar.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.EAST);

        panel.add(topBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    }

    private void createScene() {

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {

                WebView view = new WebView();
                engine = view.getEngine();

                engine.titleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, final String newValue) {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override public void run() {
                                frame.setTitle(newValue);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                engine.setOnStatusChanged(new EventHandler<WebEvent<String>>() {
                    @Override public void handle(final WebEvent<String> event) {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override public void run() {
                                lblStatus.setText(event.getData());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                engine.locationProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String oldValue, final String newValue) {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override public void run() {
                                txtURL.setText(newValue);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                engine.getLoadWorker().workDoneProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldValue, final Number newValue) {
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override public void run() {
                                progressBar.setValue(newValue.intValue());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                engine.getLoadWorker()
                        .exceptionProperty()
                        .addListener(new ChangeListener<Throwable>() {

                            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Throwable> o, Throwable old, final Throwable value) {
                                if (engine.getLoadWorker().getState() == FAILED) {
                                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override public void run() {
                                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                                                    panel,
                                                    (value != null) ?
                                                    engine.getLocation() + "\n" + value.getMessage() :
                                                    engine.getLocation() + "\nUnexpected error.",
                                                    "Loading error...",
                                                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });

                jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(view));
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadURL(final String url) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                String tmp = toURL(url);

                if (tmp == null) {
                    tmp = toURL("http://" + url);
                }

                engine.load(tmp);
            }
        });
    }

    private static String toURL(String str) {
        try {
            return new URL(str).toExternalForm();
        } catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override public void run() {

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 600));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        initComponents();

        loadURL("http://oracle.com");

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SimpleSwingBrowser());
    }
}
```

[This link](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm) also provides some helpful examples of `WebView` including demonstrating use `of` JavaScript

References:

- [Integrating JavaFX into Swing Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm)
- [Add Java FX 2.0 to existing Netbeans project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671597/add-java-fx-2-0-to-existing-netbeans-project)

Comment: @MadProgrammer +1 thank you i'd love to take credit for the code but it was just ripped from the reference :P

Comment: Yes, but you knew where to find it ;)