# How do I style HTML in a JEditorPane?

Tags: java, html, css, swing, jeditorpane

I'm completely lost on this. Would I need the CSS that is explicitly referenced in the HTML file? If so, how would I get it, and how would I apply the CSS to the HTML? I read something about JSoup being able to get the CSS.

Comment: Again forget `JSoup`. `JEditorPane` renders no higher than HTML 3.2. Have a look at [Cobra](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp)

Comment: Have a look at JavaFX supports up to HTML5. See this similar amswer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717769/jeditorpane-javascript-and-css-support/13718130#13718130

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How to add stylesheet for JEditorPane](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/how-add-style-stylesheet-jeditorpane-example-code).
In general `http://` and `file://` includes and embedded CSS are no problem.

Comment: How do I get HTML styled if there isn't embedded CSS?

Comment: The link shows how to add styles programmatically, quite easy.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373621/loading-images-from-jars-for-swing-html/6373907#6373907).

Answer (score 1):

Use a style="" attribute in the individual HTML tags

Comment: Sorry, but this does not answer my questions.