# JavaFX error when ending Swing application

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I have a Swing application in which I need to display internally generated HTML/CSS. In order to do this, I have adapted [the code from this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717769/jeditorpane-javascript-and-css-support/13718130#13718130).

The control works fine. However, when the application ends, I receive the error

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f9622171ae8, pid=5782, tid=140283095549696
```

For what it's worth, the sample code directly from Oracle (quoted in the StackOverflow post) has the same problem.

I have tried explicitly calling `Platform.exit()` when the window closes, but the error remains. So, how does one shut down JavaFX correctly, when it is embedded in a Swing application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution, at least for this application:

- This is a multi-window application; the JavaFX component is not in the main application window, but in a sub-window.
- The JavaFX "Platform" has a setting "ImplicitExit", which is by default "true".
- JavaFX Platform.exit() is apparently called both when the sub-window is closed, and when the main application is closed. This second call (when the application is closed) generates the error message described in the original question.
- The "implicit exit" behavior is in any case undesirable, because it prevents the sub-window from being re-opened a second time during the application's lifetime.

Hence, the solution is to turn off "implicit exit". Here's the JavaFX initialization code in the subwindow:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        view = new WebView();
        engine = view.getEngine();
        jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(view));
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false); // Otherwise cannot open report window a second time
    }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling Platform.exit then in the case setImplicitExit(false) has been set otherwise JavaFx thread will keep on running?