# Import webpage containing HTML, CSS and jQuery to Java Swing

Tags: java, jquery, html, css, swing

I want to import my html file with css styling (not necessarily inline) and jquery script etc.
So far I have tried jEditorPane and called setPage(url) function for this. But it only displays plain HTML file without any styling or scripting.
Kindly suggest some solution considering that I am using Netbeans 8.0.

Comment: Swing only has limited support of CSS and HTML 3.2, you're going to be out of luck with JavaScript.  Not used it myself, but consider having a look at JavaFX's webview

Comment: +1 for MadProgrammer . Also please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717769/jeditorpane-javascript-and-css-support)