# Is there a possibility rendering a HTML File into a Java Swing Component (JPanel, etc.)?

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup, html-parsing

See question above.
I found a library called JSoup which makes it possible to kid of parse HTML into the console but how do I do that into a Jpanel or other Component?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, have a [look here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) for information about using text components [and here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) for information on how JEditorPane supports HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Actually my html code which Iwant to include seems to be too complicated for JEditorPane (there is a script tag in it).

Comment: Do you need JavaScript to run or is JEditorPane not rendering because of the script element?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717769/jeditorpane-with-javascript-and-css-support

Comment: Sadly I am not allowed to use any version above JAVA SE 11 :/

Comment: I want to inclue a online weather forecast and there are several weather widget html codes but I can't use them in a JEditorPane

Comment: Is there a text-based weather forecast which I could include maybe? Or can I use Jsoup to that and if yes, how?

Comment: Java 11 should be fine, no? This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547362/javafx-and-openjdk

Comment: You can try using a Jsoup Cleaner to restrict HTML to what the JEditorPane support: https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Cleaner.html Depends on how the data source works. Does the source not provide an API for  the same data so you could render the data yourself?

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged here.  While your links are useful, please consider adding a summary of the information they contain, and a short example of how one might use that information (for example, an example that places HTML in a JLabel and another example that loads HTML in a JEditorPane).